# IServiceCollection StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried moving all my DI instructions to a separate class using an extension method, on runtime I get a stack-overflow exception with no further details

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var dns_client = new LookupClient();

    services.AddSingleton<ImySQLService, mySQLService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerService, LoggerService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IOrginizationRepository, OrginizationRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEdiModelRepository, EdiModelRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEdiUserProfileRepository, EdiUserProfileRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEdiSegmentRepository, EdiSegmentRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionRepository, ConnectionRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IVariableRepository, VariableRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISegmentPictureRepository, SegmentPictureRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEdiExampleRepository, EdiExampleRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDocumentReceiverRepository, DocumentReceiverRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDocumentToEdiRepository, DocumentToEdiRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEdiValidatorRepository, EdiValidatorRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDnsLookupRepository, DnsLookupRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<ILookupClient>(dns_client);
    services.AddHttpClient<IPylonAPIService, PylonAPIService>();
    ...

    return services;
}
```

- What could possibly be causing this?
- How would I got about debugging such an exception that has no further messages
- I tried to wrap it with try - catch but to no avail

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Must be that something in your code inside your routine causes the `AddMyServices` to be called recursively. I would go about this excluding all and than including them one by one again.

Comment: @PaulSinnema sounds reasonable , how would I go about debuging that?

Comment: From within Visual Studio, you can inspect the stack trace when a StackOverflowException happens. Just make sure VS breaks on all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I had

```
builder.Services.AddMyServices();
```

twice , once in my Program.cs and once in the Extension Method itself